# Measure theory problem involving limits and integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, problem-solving

I found a problem in the ISI JRF sample question paper.The question is as follows:

> If $f_1,f_2,...,f\geq 0$ are Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^y f_n(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^y f(x)dx$  for every $y\in \mathbb R\cup \{+\infty\}$.Show that $\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}\ \int_U f_n(x)dx\geq \int_U f(x)dx$ for any open subset $U\subset \mathbb R$.

Here is my attempt:

Take any open interval $(a,b)$ with $-\infty\leq a<b\leq +\infty$,then we can show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f_n(x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx$.This follows due to the fact that $\int_a^b=\int_{-\infty}^b-\int_{-\infty}^a$.Now take any open subset $U\subset \mathbb R$ then we have a result that $U$ can be written as a disjoint union of countably many open intervals.So we write $U=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty(a_n,b_n)$ which is a countable disjoint union of open intervals.Let $U_m=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^m (a_k,b_k)$.Now, $\int_{U_m} f_n(x)dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f_n(x)dx$ and $\int_{U_m} f(x)dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\int_{a_k}^{b_k} f(x)dx$.Now note that $U_m\uparrow U$ as $m\to \infty$.Since $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable non-negative functions,so $\nu_n(E)=\int_E f_n(x)dx$ and $\nu(E)=\int_E f(x)dx$ are measures on $\mathbb R$.Now  measures are continuous with respect to increasing limits which gives $\nu_n(U_m)\uparrow \nu_n(U)$ as $m\to \infty$ which can be rewritten as $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \int_{U_m} f_n(x)dx=\int_U f_n(x)dx$.In a similar way, $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \int_{U_m} f(x)dx=\int_U f(x)dx$.But for a fixed $m$,we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f_n(x)dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\int_{a_k}^{b_k} f(x)dx$ which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{U_m} f_n(x)dx=\int_{U_m} f(x)dx$.Now we apply limit as $m\to \infty$ on both sides,to get $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{U_m} f_n(x)dx=\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\int_{U_m} f(x)dx=\int_U f(x)dx$.Now on the left hand side we can interchange the limits without any problem as the integral inside the interated limit is non-negative.So we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\int_{U_m} f_n(x)dx=\int_U f(x)dx$ and this implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_U f_n(x)dx=\int_U f(x)dx$.

I am not sure whether my solution is correct because even if it is correct I have deduced something stronger than demanded in the question.That's why I have a doubt whether I did it correctly or there is some error hidden in this solution.Can anyone check if it is okay?

Comment: Overall seems correct but you need to give more justification for the interchange of iterated limits. Just being non-negative is not enough. For instance the iterated limit of $\frac{n}{n+m}$ are 1 and 0, hence not equal.

Comment: The iterated limits seems wrong to me. Consider the following double sequence $a_{m,n} := (m+n)/n \ge 0$ for each $m,n \in \mathbb N$. One of the limits is $1$ and other is $\infty$.

Comment: @NewB Can you give a proper argument as to why the limits can be interchanged.

Comment: There's this theorem I recall which says that the iterated limits of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ exists and are equal if the double limit exist and $\lim_n a_{n,m}$ exists for each large $m$ and $\lim_m a_{n,m}$ exist for each large $n$. You can try this. Frankly, I don't know if this will work out.

Comment: One possible way is to consider for open $U$ it's indicator function $\mathcal{X}_U$. It  is measurable, so $\mathcal{X}_U\cdot f_n$ will be integrable with same limit property. And we come to $\lim$ and $\lim\inf$ relation.

Comment: Another possible way is to extract the information that $\lim\inf f_n(x)\geq f(x)$ for $\mu$-a.e from the given information and then apply Fataou's lemma.

Comment: This doesn't justify OP's limit interchange claim, but here is a simple way to get what the original problem was asking. The non-negativity of each $f_n$ and the fact $U_m \subset U$ implies $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{U_m} f_n(x)\,dx \leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{U} f_n\,dx = \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{U} f_n\,dx.$$